# creating Chrome compatible .mp4 with ffmpeg from commandline

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg

How do you encode en .mp4 file from commandline with ffmpeg, so it works in chrome? This can be really challenging, because ffmpeg has a lot of parameter combinations and Chrome are sensitive to the color encoding of the output format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use the parameter "-pix_fmt yuv420p":

```
ps>ffmpeg.exe -i $input\$file -y -strict experimental -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 160k -vcodec libx264 -s 640x480 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 30 -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -b 1200k -f mp4 -threads 0 $output\$file.iphone.mp4
```

ffmpeg version N-46936-g8b6aeb1

Hopes this can help you with getting chrome compatible videos

Comment: Note that x264 should have warned you about pixel formats other than `yuv420p` not being compatible with the baseline profile, e.g. 4:2:2 content.

Comment: Is all of that required, or just the "-pix_fmt yuv420p"? I am using "-pix_fmt yuv420p" and have found that (only recently?) my videos do not work in Chrome, either are blank, or fail randomly half way.